# MYSQL error.log showing failed login attempts as [note]

Tags: mysql, fail2ban

I am trying to use fail2ban with MYSQL 5.7.19

The error.log shows entries like this:

```
2017-10-03T19:17:45.014850Z 127207 [Note] Access denied for user 'trafic'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
2017-10-03T19:17:46.222136Z 127209 [Note] Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
2017-10-03T19:17:47.440388Z 127211 [Note] Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
2017-10-03T19:17:48.625799Z 127213 [Note] Access denied for user 'wordpress'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
2017-10-03T19:17:49.849088Z 127219 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Neither any IP is captured in the error.log nor it is shown as warning, but is logged as a `[note]`

I have set the `log-warnings =2` in `mysqld.cnf`

Thanks.

update:
I have these logs from mysql error.log more than 20 times from the same ip.

```
2017-10-04T14:35:45.932144Z 218879 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'123.129.218.64' (using password: YES)
2017-10-04T14:35:46.551180Z 218881 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'123.129.218.64' (using password: YES)
2017-10-04T14:35:47.169756Z 218882 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'123.129.218.64' (using password: YES)
```

and my fail2ban filter code is like this:

```
[Definition]

_daemon = mysqld

failregex = ^%(__prefix_line)s(\d{6} \s?\d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2} )?\[Warning\] Access denied for user '\w+'@'<HOST>' (to database '[^']*'|\(using password: (YES|N$

ignoreregex =
```

and jail.conf looks like this:

```
[mysql]
enabled = true
port = 3306
filter =  mysqld-auth
logpath = /var/log/mysql/error.log
maxretry = 3
```

but fail2ban is not picking up the failed attempts.

I have also tried for a wrong user multiple times with PhpMyadmin in browser. so it automatically adds `localhost` to the user, even though I am trying it remotely.

so the question is I can try innumerable times in PhpMyadmin with failed attempts without being banned.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: 1. I want to configure fail2ban - for that there should be IP in the error.log 2. does `access denied for user` shouldn't be logged as warning and not as `[note]`

Comment: You should rephrase your post to include a questions(s) and add what you tried as in how you have fail2ban configured

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If MySQL isn't behaving, you can edit your fail2ban regex (`failregex`) to detect the "Note" instead of "Warning"

```
failregex = ^%(__prefix_line)s(\d{6} \s?\d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2} )?\[Warning\] Access denied for user '\w+'@'<HOST>' (to database '[^']*'|\(using password: (YES|NO)\))*\s*$
```

to:

```
failregex = ^%(__prefix_line)s(?:\d+ |\d{6} \s?\d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2} )?\[\w+\] Access denied for user '[^']+'@'<HOST>' (to database '[^']*'|\(using password: (YES|NO)\))*\s*$
```

You can test this using:

```
fail2ban-regex "2017-10-04T14:35:47.169756Z 218882 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'123.129.218.64' (using password: YES)" /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/mysqld-auth.conf
```

And you will see a match in the output:

```
Lines: 1 lines, 0 ignored, 1 matched, 0 missed [processed in 0.00 sec]
```

Comment: but there is no ip in the log. so how fail2ban will ban it?

Comment: The IP of the offending user will be in the username line 'root'@'x.x.x.x' if they are remote. If they are not remote, you have another, much worse, security issue at hand.

Comment: you mean `[Note] Access denied for user 'trafic'@'localhost' (using password: YES)` is being tried locally by some script and if yes, is there any way to locate the offending script?

Comment: If it's running at regular intervals (time wise) check your cron log, daemon logs, maybe there'll be something there. If that's what you're attempting to ban fail2ban will block everything on localhost and likely break something you actually want.

Comment: Hi Darryl - please have a look at my updates. There are two concerns First is if some tries throrugh PhpMyadmin, it is always localhost, so will never get banned. second is even where there is remote ip in the host part, the fail2ban is not picking that.

Comment: I see. The old regex is old. It's not matching the date stamp. I've updated the regex from the most current fail2ban version.

Comment: Changing the failregex for the mysqld-auth filter to the above pattern worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

As per MySql 8.0.28 installed on Ubuntu 20.04 the following is working:

**Fail regex**

located in `/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/mysqld-auth.conf`

```
failregex = ^(?:(?:\d{6}|\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})T\s?\d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d*Z)?(?:\d+ )?.*Access denied for user '[^']+'@'<HOST>' (to database '[^']*'|\(using password: (YES|NO)\))*\s*$
```

**MySQL Logging**

Note, there is a bit strange behavior of MySql logging - failed attempts are not logged into file defined in `log_error` variable, but only to general log file.

General logging has to be turned on manually by following configuration in `etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`  file:

```
general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/query.log
general_log             = 1
```

**Fail2Ban Jail**

And for completion the jail configuration, located in `/etc/fail2ban/jail.local`

```
[mysqld-auth]
enabled  = true
port     = 3306
filter   = mysqld-auth
logpath  = /var/log/mysql/query.log
```